# instagram scraper : IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, web-scraping, instagram

using the [instagram-scraper](https://github.com/arc298/instagram-scraper) library results in this error.

using the [instagram-scraper](https://github.com/arc298/instagram-scraper) library results in this error.

for example `instagram-scraper <username>` gives this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/instagram_scraper/app.py", line 652, in __get_media_details
    return self._get_json(resp)['graphql']['shortcode_media']
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/instagram_scraper/app.py", line 159, in _get_json
    return json.loads(text)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/__init__.py", line 319, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/instagram-scraper", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/instagram_scraper/app.py", line 1597, in main
    scraper.scrape()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/instagram_scraper/app.py", line 706, in scrape
    self.get_media(dst, executor, future_to_item, user)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/instagram_scraper/app.py", line 853, in get_media
    unit=' media', disable=self.quiet):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tqdm/std.py", line 1195, in __iter__
    for obj in iterable:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/instagram_scraper/app.py", line 963, in query_media_gen
    media, end_cursor = self.__query_media(user['id'], end_cursor)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/instagram_scraper/app.py", line 991, in __query_media
    nodes = self._get_nodes(container)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/instagram_scraper/app.py", line 593, in _get_nodes
    return [self.augment_node(node['node']) for node in container['edges']]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/instagram_scraper/app.py", line 593, in <listcomp>
    return [self.augment_node(node['node']) for node in container['edges']]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/instagram_scraper/app.py", line 612, in augment_node
    details = self.__get_media_details(node['shortcode'])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/instagram_scraper/app.py", line 655, in __get_media_details
    data = resp.split("window.__additionalDataLoaded(")[1].split("});</script>")[0].split('{"graphql":')[1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

i'm guessing something is wrong with my pip or python setup.

Comment: Is that the full output of your program? The traceback looks quite similar to [this issue](https://github.com/arc298/instagram-scraper/issues/790)

Answer (score 0):

Your pip and python setups are probably fine.

The problem is that Instagram updated its structure, and now __additionalDataLoaded as well as _sharedData returns empty.